# 40 minutes of transit time at AMS for Dublin to Germany?

Tags: transit, ams

I bought a ticket from KLM, I'm travelling back from Ireland to Germany, non EU citizen and only have a 40 minute layover. Is this possible? I had initially assumed this would be similar to a intra schengen flight, but I think there would be passport control since Ireland is not in Schengen, but only EU (I do hold a visa to Ireland and a residency in Germany), so would 40 minutes be about OK to make this connection?

Comment: There is a special area for the passport control which only transfer passengers will use, as I never have transfered at AMS, I can not tell you how long the wait will be.

Answer (score -2):

On the [airport website](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/page/passports-and-travel-documents/) it clearly states you will need to pass through passport control:

> ## Standard passport control at Schiphol
>
> When travelling from Schiphol to a non-Schengen country, you have to pass through Passport Control. Your passport is also checked when you arrive from a non-Schengen country. These checks are carried out by the Royal Netherlands Marechaussee, a branch of the Dutch armed forces with police powers.

Passport control is usually sped up by KLM.

If your flight is delayed by a little bit it is quite likely you will miss the connection. In some cases, KLM may hold the flight a bit if a lot of passengers are transferring (bear in mind this is their hub).

A personal suggestion, don't book the latest flight fro AMS-Germany so if your flight is delayed you don't have to stay in a hotel overnight like I did.

It is doable though, so your choice.

Comment: When you missed your flight, did the airline do all the hotel+rebooking etc. Was it because of a flight delay or just because of immigration delay? If it's the latter is the airline responsible for rebooking you?

Comment: @xworder it was a combination of both, yes the hotel and new flight was rebooked

Comment: so my question is if the flight does almost land on time, and the passport control gets delayed, is the airline responsible for rebooking?

Comment: @xworder Yes it is

Comment: @DaniilManokhin This answer is wrong. OP needs to clear passport control because they're entering the Schengen Area

Comment: Are you the Daniil who was removed because of low age? Are you old enough now?

Comment: @Crazydre sorry, updated

Comment: @guest yes I was, see here: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/announcing-my-possible-return-to-travel-se

Comment: Great!!! Welcome back!!!